# Zero acceleration in circular motion while the body is accelerating

Tags: kinematics, reference-frames, rotational-kinematics

I was going through László Holics book (300 Creative Problems in Physics) and came across this question:

> The radius of the tire of a car is $R$. The valve cap is at a distance $r$ from the axis of the wheel. The car starts from rest without skidding, at constant acceleration. Is it possible, in some way, that the valve cap has no acceleration in the following cases?
>
> (a) In the $\frac{1}{8}$ turn following the bottom position
>
> (b) In the $\frac{1}{8}$ turn preceding the bottom position

I tried solving it myself but got an answer that didn't match the solutions of the chapter. I then read both the approaches to the problem, and it referred to two expressions/terms which I didn't understand, namely:$$\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}=r\cdot\frac{a}{R}$$ and $$r\cdot\left(\frac{a}{R}\cdot t\right)^{2}$$

Could anyone explain to me what are these terms and how do I use them to solve the question? I'll be grateful for any new methods to solve this question too.

P.S. I'm uploading the scanned copy of the solution pages for reference (Problem 6). Sorry for the ambiguous title, I couldn't think of a better way to describe it. Could someone edit it to reflect the question more appropriately...? :)

[image: Page 1]
[image: Page 2]
[image: Page 3]
[image: Page 4]
[image: Page 5]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way in which the acceleration of the valve cap can ever be zero is if the relative acceleration of the valve cap w.r.t. the car cancels out the acceleration of the car itself.

For case (a) that is impossible, because this condition requires that the vector opposing $\vec{a}$ (i.e. $-\vec{a}$) must point in a direction between the normal and tangential acceleration of the cap (due to the car's rotation).

For case (b), this can only occur if $\vec{a}_n + \vec{a}_t = - \vec{a}$. The two components are also at a 90° angle to each other, s.t. $a_n^2 + a_t^2 = a^2$ must hold. As we know that we are in the $1/8$ rotation before the bottom (at $45°$ to the vertical), both $\vec{a}_n$ and $\vec{a}_t$ must also be at 45° to the horizontal, and therefore have the same magnitude, $a' = a_n = a_t = a/ \sqrt{2}$. So far, so good. Now to the points you raised:

First: The angular acceleration of the wheel $\ddot \phi$ is given by $a/R$. However, we know that that must also equal the tangential acceleration anywhere along the plane of the wheel, s.t. $\ddot \phi = a_t / r$. Now $a_t = a' = a / \sqrt{2}$ s.t. $a / \sqrt{2} = r \cdot a / R$. That yields the expected $r = R / \sqrt{2}$.

Second: The normal acceleration originates from a centripetal force, s.t. $a_n = r\dot \phi^2 = r (v / R)^2 = r(a\cdot t / R)^2$. As this must equal the tangential acceleration $a_t = r \cdot a / R$, we obtain the solution for time. Finally, this leads us to a change in angle $\varphi$ (from the starting angle of the valve), which allows us to calculate the exact conditions under which the valve can ever have 0 acceleration.

I hope this helps and let me know if you have any other questions!

Comment: I have a couple of queries (they may be trivial, but sorry, I haven't learned the concept in its entirety yet)
How is the angular acceleration $\ddot{\phi}$ given by $\frac{a}{R}$? I understood how $\ddot{\phi}=\frac{a_t}{R}$.

Comment: I didn't understand the following equation in the book too:
$$\left(r\cdot\frac{a}{R}\cdot t\right)^{2}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+r\cdot\frac{a}{R}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}=a$$
Isn't the acceleration supposed to just be $$\vec{a}={-r\dot{\phi}}^{2} \hat{r} + r\ddot{\phi}\hat{\phi}$$

How did the $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ get involved in the equation?

Comment: @Dogewithshades We can define the distance traveled (without skidding) as $x = \phi R$ (where $\phi$ is in radians). From that, it follows that $v = \dot x = \dot \phi R$ and therefore $a = \dot v = \ddot \phi R$. Also note that $\ddot \phi = a_t / r \neq a_t / R$, unlike what you said above.

Comment: @Dogewithshades the equation containing $\sqrt 2 / 2$ comes directly from the condition on the x and y components of the acceleration. Rather than working in polar coordinates (radial and tangential motion), we can change basis to the Euclidian coordinates x and y. These are related to the polar ones by the transforms in the LHS of equation (1) and (2). Noting that the angle is 45° s.t. $sin(\alpha) = cos(\alpha) = \sqrt 2 / 2$, and substitutiting terms I explained in my answer into equations (1) and (2) (which are the x and y conditions for 0 acceleration), we obtain that result.

Comment: Okay, I got both of my doubts resolved. Thank you so much! Really lucid explanation!